# American Vandal leg brace: clue or continuity error?

Tags: continuity, american-vandal

In American Vandal, there's at least two different scenes where Christa Carlyle has a cast on. But it's on different legs in two of the shots.

[image]

Did they make a mistake? Or was this supposed to be one of the clues? It seems odd that they seemed to miss this part when they were talking about whether or not the cast was faked towards the end of the season.

Comment: [Related](https://www.bustle.com/p/these-american-vandal-theories-explore-who-drew-the-graffiti-provide-seriously-compelling-evidence-2375282)